# Problem in Multinomial Theorem

Tags: multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

> If $n$ & $k$ are positive integers such that $$n \ge \frac{(k)(k+1)}{2}$$
>   then the number of solutions $(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ such that $x_1 \ge 1 , x_2 \ge 2,..., x_k \ge k$ are all integers satisfying $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = n$$ is?

My attempt at a solution:

The answer equals the coefficient of $x^n$ in the following 
$$(x+x^2+x^3+....)(x^2+x^3+x^4+...)...(x^k+x^{k+1}...)$$
This equals 
$$x^{\frac {k(k+1)}{2}}(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)^k$$
This is where I'm stuck. How do I find the coefficient of $x^n$ if I don't know what it equals?

Comment: It's equivalent to say $(x_1-1)+(x_2-2)+\dotsb+(x_k-k)=n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, where each $x_i-i \geq 0$. Do you know the number of ways to write a nonnegative integer, $n - \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, as a sum of $k$ nonnegative integers?

Comment: Right, that's it. $n-\frac {{k}{(k+1)}}{2}+k-1 \choose k-1$. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you got a very nice approach so far. So here is an answer which follows your approach  further.

The number of solutions is to be given *as a function of k and n*.  Now with your approach, that number is  the number of terms with power $p = n - \frac {k(k+1)}{2}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)^k$.

Let $|x| <1$ then the sum in parantheses is (geometric series)

$$
\frac{1}{1-x}
$$

So the power you are looking for  is given by expansion of

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^k}
$$

into a series about $x=0$, where (Taylor) the coefficient with power $p$ has the factor

$$
\frac{1}{p!} \frac{d^{(p)}f(x)}{dx^{(p)}} |_{x=0}
$$

Now taking the derivatives is easy to see:

$$
\frac{d^{(p)}f(x)}{dx^{(p)}}  = \frac{k(k+1) \cdots (k+p-1)}{(1-x)^{k+p}}
$$

so the factor in  the Taylor expansion is

$$
\frac{k(k+1) \cdots (k+p-1)}{p!} = \frac{(k+p-1)!}{p! (k-1)!} = \binom{k+p-1}{k-1}
$$

Finally, plugging in 
$p = n - \frac {k(k+1)}{2}$ from above, we get

$$
\binom{k-1+n - \frac {k(k+1)}{2} }{k-1}
$$